# xcode 7.3.1: Build Failed when using cocoapods 1.0.1

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I successfully "pod install" a dependency of "AwesomeTextField" in a simple project via cocoapods.

[image]

**Here is the Podfile**:
[image]

However, when I build the project. It gives me an **error**.

[image]

I open the project via clicking CoTe.xcodeproj. Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should open CoTe.xcworkspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use CocoaPods, you must open the Workspace file, not the .xcodeproj file.

Look for a file with the extension `.xcworkspace`. Perhaps it is called `CoTe.xcworkspace`.